# In magento how to create a link in footer

Tags: magento

I have created a CMS page named Shipping from my magento admin CMS->pages.Now i need to create a link in footer as shipping and have to link the shipping-CMS page to the link.How to create a link in magento footer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just go to Open Admin panel and go to CMS>static block and Open `footer_links` static block and add new link to just like that

```
<li><a href="{{store direct_url="YOUR_CMS_PAGEURL"}}">YOUR CMS PAGE NAME</a></li>
```

Or open `footer.phtml` from app\design\frontend\YOUR_PACKAGE_NAME\YOUR_THEME_NAME\template\page\html

and add your link .

Comment: Even after clear the cache also it remains same.I cant see any additional link

Comment: in which place you are changing?

Comment: I have updated the footer_links static block and added the code which you have mentioned above and replaced it with my cms page url.

Comment: you are using default magento theme?or anu custom theme? just try to update footer.phtml,,check whether it will add link o not

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/42766/discussion-between-rama-priya-and-keyur-shah)